# Where could I find drivers of ATI Radeon 2400 HD?

Tags: drivers, ati, 64-bit, 12.10

Where could I find drivers of ATI Radeon 2400 HD Ubuntu 12.10 x64, for laptop?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the [AMD website](http://support.amd.com/us/Pages/AMDSupportHub.aspx).
2. Select the appropriate categories in their drop downs (see image)
3. Click "**View Results**". You found the driver. Congratulations!

[image]

To install them:

1. Run in terminal:

   ```
   sudo sh ati-driver-installer-10-3-x86.x86_64.run
   ```

   Note:-if the filename is different, then change the name. You will be asked for your password.
2. Select the first option, then click next, then **use all the recommended options**.
3. To get sound working right click on the sound icon on the top right, click sound preferences. Go to Output and select the RV630 or whichever your one is.
4. If the sound still doesn't work, go into a terminal window again and type:

   ```
   killall pulseaudio
   sudo alsa force-reload
   ```

Source: [Ubuntu Geek](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-ati-radeon-hd-2600-drivers-in-ubuntu.html). Google is your friend.

Comment: it also requires to do "aticonfig --initial"