# How do I install the latest ATI Catalyst Video Drivers in Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal?

Tags: drivers, ati, video, 12.10, catalyst

There are other threads related to this question for Ubuntu 12.04, however THEY DO NOT APPLY TO 12.10. This is not a duplicate of another thread if the referenced thread doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: what about installing it from the jockey(Additional Drivers) ?

Comment: or this ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/204129/where-could-i-find-drivers-of-ati-radeon-2400-hd

Comment: I just get a "no proprietary drivers are in use" notice. No option to install the drivers.

Comment: Please consider marking my answer.

Answer (score 4):

For the purpose of this question: Catalyst = fglrx = proprietary AMD/ATI display driver

The most problems people are having come from the fact that:
1. Ubuntu has moved to newer driver versions, that don't support some older ATI/AMD chips
2. Ubuntu has moved to newer Xorg versions

Symptoms:
No. 1 - **'not supported'** errors / **Jockey** not detecting proprietary drivers valid for installation
No. 2 - some older ATI/AMD Catalyst versions won't install

**Which all comes down to:
Your chip is no longer supported by the latest ATI/AMD catalyst display drivers (be it via manual install or from Ubuntu repositories)**

Solution:
Check, what is the latest driver version that supports your chip and then proceed with the installation accordingly.
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware (may be slightly outdated)
or
enter your graphic card details here:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx 
use terminal command to display information about your graphics

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

If the latest version for you is 12.6 => proceed as per https://askubuntu.com/a/201785/29347

**Chips that are indicated 'legacy' (not supported for the latest Catalyst versions):**
Try the PPA listed here [How to install old AMD Catalyst 12.4 drivers on Ubuntu 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201541/how-to-install-old-amd-catalyst-12-4-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-10)
You'll most probably get Catalyst 12.6

Chips that ARE supported in 12.10 / by the latest Catalyst drivers: 
The installation should be accomplished as per [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

Comment: That's odd, I have a Radeon 4870 which is still one of the better cards available.

Comment: @ChrisBauer According to the sources I've just added above your 4000 is 'legacy' already. Gotta love planned obsolescence ;)

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help. I'll look into this when I have more time. Looks like my next card will be a Nvidia :)

Answer (score 1):

The latest ATI catalyst for Ubuntu 12.10 I know of is this one:
**AMD Catalyst 12,9 driver**

First Uninstall the current driver AMD with these commands:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh 
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev* xorg-driver-fglrx
```

#### Manual installation:

To install AMD Catalyst 12.9 in Ubuntu 12.10/12.04/11.10 run the following commands from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
cd /tmp && wget -O amd-12.9-9.00-EDG_Direct.zip http://www2.ati.com/drivers/embedded/9.00-120815a-146426C-EDG_Direct.zip
unzip amd-12.9-9.00-EDG_Direct.zip
chmod +x amd-driver-installer-9.00-x86.x86_64.run 
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-9.00-x86.x86_64.run
```

And then after the installation was finished run this command:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Then reboot.

---

*Note:* PPA has not been updated so far, but the driver will be updated soon.
To install the driver provided by **xorg-edgers**, open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx-installer
```

Comment: I'm getting one of the errors I get fairly often in my various attempts to install the driver: "Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed."

I've tried googling the error to no avail.

Comment: I also tried adding the xorg-edgers/ppa repository and installing fglrx-installer, but I don't know what to do after that. Running fglrx-installer at terminal gives a bad command error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the latest version of Ati Catalyst 12.11 (beta) and 12.10 (stable) that has just been released ,you can find it  here : http://www.upubuntu.com/search/label/System  hope it will work .

Comment: Thanks, but both the 12.11 and 12.10 versions are giving me the "Your graphics adapter is not supported by this driver" error.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to update your ATI / AMD Catalyst Proprietary Display Drivers to the latest release, or would like to try the latest AMD Catalyst BETA drivers, have look at :

[The Fan Club - Ubuntu AMD Catalyst install](http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-amd-catalyst-install)

- The application auto detects your ATI / AMD graphics hardware and
  selects the best driver options to install.
- This application downloads, creates DEB packages and installs the
  latest AMD Catalyst™ Proprietary Display Drivers for Ubuntu
  32bit/64bit.
- You can also install the latest AMD Catalyst™ Proprietary Display
  BETA Drivers as well as Legacy AMD Catalyst™ Proprietary Display
  Drivers if your hardware is supported.